# Как заставить массив php выдавать данные по мере их определения в массиве, а не по индексу?

Tags: php

Допустим задан такой массив:

`$arr = array(1 => "a", 3 => "b", 2 => "c");`

Если ли возможность сохранить последовательность чтения данных из массив в том порядке как элементы были заданы? Т.е. чтобы какой-нибудь

`foreach($arr as $item) echo($item);`

давал на выходе `abc`, а не `acb`?

Comment: Дак оно итак `abc` выведет для такого массива. А если массив вида `acb`, то отсортируйте его по значениям.

Comment: Нет, выдает `acb`. Массив индексный, `foreach` идет последовательно по индексам, от меньшего к большему. Отсортировать по значениям нельзя, это тут в модельном коде `a, c, b`, в боевом массиве значение сортировка которых так же собьет порядок.

Comment: Перейдите по ссылке и нажмите [Execute code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/eb2a228b7da129ad8cda2271221085e4ce82f4c2)

Comment: [Map](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.ds-map.php) Сохраняется порядок вставки.

Comment: @Эдуард мистика. У меня 7.3, но вряд ли это имеет значение...

Comment: @AndreyFedorov очень даже может иметь значение. Аналогичный "мистический" пример с квадратными скобками в php 5.4, который в php 5.3 вызывает ошибку парсинга. Про сортировку я так и не понял вашего аргумента, но есть `asort()`, она сохраняет связь между ключами и значениями.

Comment: @Эдуард боевая задача такая - у меня есть массив в котором описаны тайлы подкатегорий товаров. я хочу чтобы в листинге категории подкатегории стояли в определенном порядке и этот порядок можно было поменять простым изменением индекса в массиве. При этом я не хочу задавать в массиве еще одно поле отвечающее за порядок элементов.

Comment: @AndreyFedorov может имеет смысл добавить пример вашего массива в пост с вопросом?

Comment: @Эдуард все равно уже минусы и голосуют чтобы закрыть вопрос. ладно буду дальше мучаться. спасибо.

Comment: @Эдуард не поверите - решил. ) Стоит написать вопрос на so сразу придумывается решение. ) просто дополнительный индекс считаю вручную, как в циклах вроде while.